# Change color of selected item to black and keep place holder's color grey in React Picky

Tags: css, reactjs

Using react picky for the multiselect dropdown. Trying to keep the placeholder color to grey while having the color black after selection.

Html

```
<Picky multiple={true}
       includeFilter={true}
       onChange={this.onRulesSelectChange}
       placeholder={"Please Select"} />
```

In css overriding picky's placeholder class but it applying on selected text as well. So text is also going grey.

CSS

```
.picky__placeholder{
    font-family: CSePRoman, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: grey;
    line-height: 21px;
}
```

**Actual**

Placeholder -> Grey

Selected Text -> Grey

**Expected**

Placeholder -> Grey

Selected text -> Black

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just selected the class name which stays the same on the element if you select items or not. 
If you want to color the initial none selected value grey you can do this.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      arrayValue: []
    };
    this.onRulesSelectChange = this.onRulesSelectChange.bind(this);
  }

  //Set the updated value array in your state
  onRulesSelectChange(value) {
    this.setState({ arrayValue: value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
            <h3>Multi select</h3>
            <Picky
              //Conditionally assign a class based on size values selected
              className={
                this.state.arrayValue.length > 0 ? "items-selected" : "items-not-selected"
              }
              value={this.state.arrayValue}
              options={??} //Put in your options as you did 
              multiple={true}
              includeFilter={true}
              onChange={this.onRulesSelectChange}
              placeholder={"Please Select"}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Update your css files with the following rule

```
.not-selected span.picky__placeholder {
    color: grey
}
```

Checkout this live code sandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/0zz0q9670

Comment: This made my Monday. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your wellcome @SwatiJoshi
If you found my answer helpful please consider upvoting and marking it as the answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

in react there is a way to style your components dynamically inside JSX via "classname" argument 
f.e. 
CSS:

```
.foo { color: grey;}

.bar { color: black;}
```

and then in React:

```
....
import styles from './styles'; // your css file

<div className={classNames({[styles.foo]: true, [styles.bar]: 
true})}>
  your text...
</div>
```

so you can dynamically change usage of those styles

Comment: Thank you for your response. Although I have solved my problem with @jdc91's response.